# Bitmap from BrowserField in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

In my application I am loading some HTML content in `BrowserField`. I want to get the browser content as a `Bitmap`. I used following code.

```java
Display.screenshot(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
```

But getting full screen. I need to take particular `BrowserField` as a `Bitmap`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Get the position of the BrowserField in Screen. Then use the position, and dimension of the BrowserField to extract desired area from the captured screenshot.

Comment: Hi Rupak can you explain bit more..

Comment: i tried this way..  int h = mWebView.getHeight();   int w = mWebView.getWidth(); bitmap = new Bitmap(w, h);
Display.screenshot(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h); but i got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: That's because BrowserField is bigger that screen. You probably need dimensions of manager that holds this browser field. As well don't forget left corner coordinates

Comment: i can get the left,right top, bottom of the Browser field from my manager... how can i drow the bitmap.. i got only empty bitmap

Comment: My Browser filed is bigger then the screen. i need to take full browser field as bitmap or image.. how can i achieve this...

Comment: I think you cann't get the screenshot of the whole screen using `Display.screenshot(..`. Let me know if you are able to get the screenshot of the whole screen.

Comment: @Rupak, I remember there was limitation with Bitmap fields. You can't create or bitmap bigger than screen size or when you ask it's graphics it throws some weird Exception

Comment: I tried that Rupak mentioned.. but still i cant get the full webview content...

Comment: I don't thing this is going to be possible. For one, you're definitely not going to get the whole website in using a screenshot. I would suggest using server-side scripting to convert the website into an image.

Comment: ya you are right ... i tried lot...